# Is it necessary to make this variable volatile?

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

I was going through an "JAX London 2011" [presentation on "Modern Java Concurrency"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qrCUy9H76IA). Between the time duration 43:20 - 43:40, a person from the audience says the `shutdown` variable in the code below should have been declared as `volatile` and the presenters agree with it (and say that it was pointed out earlier as well, but they just didnt get to modify the presentation). The code in question is:

```
public abstract class QueueReaderTask implements Runnable {

  private boolean shutdown = false;
  protected BlockingQueue<WorkUnit<String>> lbq;

  public void run() {
    while (!shutdown) {
      try {
        WorkUnit<String> wu = lbq.poll(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        if (wu != null) { doAction(wu.getWork()); }
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        shutdown = true;
      }
    }
  }

  public abstract void doAction(String msg);
  public void setQueue(BlockingQueue<WorkUnit<String>> q) { lbq = q; }
}
```

My Question:
I dont think that `shutdown` should be declared `volatile`.
My reasoning is that `shutdown` being a member of a `Runnable`, each task/thread will have a distinct private copy of that variable. So, why make it `volatile`?

But since this was discussed in JAX 2011, I am assuming there were lots of expert Java developers in that audience. I dont think all of them would have missed this ! 
So, what am I missing ?

P.S:-
I can understand that a variable should be declared `volatile` if it was (potentially) shared by multiple threads, as in the Double-Checked-Locking pattern :

```
class Foo {
        private volatile Helper helper = null;
        public Helper getHelper() {
            if (helper == null) {
                synchronized(this) {
                    if (helper == null)
                        helper = new Helper();
                }
            }
            return helper;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> each task/thread will have a distinct private copy of that variable. So, why make it 'volatile' ?

You are correct *if* the `shutdown` boolean is only modified from within the `QueueReaderTask` instance.  In that case `shutdown` is only being modified by the one thread and doesn't need to be `volatile`.

Frankly, the code looks strange to me.  Why catch `InterruptedException`, set the `shutdown` boolean, and then loop around and exit.  Why now just do the following? Why have the `shutdown` flag at all?

```
while (true) {
  try {
    WorkUnit<String> wu = lbq.poll(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    if (wu != null) { doAction(wu.getWork()); }
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
     Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
     return;
  }
}
```

Maybe there is extra code that was removed in the post?  If not, I wonder if this was copy and pasted from a larger section of code where `shutdown` was set to true *also* in a method call.

> P.S:- I can understand that a variable should be declared 'volatile' if it was (potentially) shared by multiple threads, as in the Double-Checked-Locking pattern :

Right.  A typical pattern is that `shutdown` is modified from another thread which is telling the thread to stop processing.  In that case it needs to be `volatile`.

Comment: Anyone want to explain the -1?

Comment: Thanks. I think it is safe to assume that 'shutdown' can only be modified from within the QueueReaderTask instance because :   a. the 'shutdown' variable is declared private.   b. the class had no "..." (meaning no paraphrasing or left-out code).   c. there was no setShutdown().   d. The meaning of the variable seems to be: 'shut myself down if I cant complete processing of an object from the queue properly'. Another thread shouldnt have to shutme down if that thread couldnt properly process an object from the queue.

Comment: I agree @VenkateshDhandapani.